# "Python was not found but can be installed" when using spark-submit on Windows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed PySpark on Windows following the steps described [here](https://deelesh.github.io/pyspark-windows.html#disqus_thread), with the Spark version 3.1.2 and the package type pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7, while the python version is 3.9.6.

I wanted to try the spark-submit with the wordcount example, so I went to the Command Prompt in the SPARK_HOME directory and I inputted this:

```
 bin\spark-submit examples\src\main\python\wordcount.py README.md
```

However, I got this message:

```
Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9NJ46SX7X90P
```

I don't know what is wrong, I made sure Python was added to PATH when I installed it and the command bin\pyspark seems to work correctly as well. I have also tried going to **Settings > Apps > App execution aliases** and disable all the python options, but it doesn't work.

**Edit:** This is the error message I get if I try the App execution aliases method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 10):

#### It's late, but here is the solution.

---

1. Go to `environment variables` window by typing in `search` environment variables

[image]

2. create a new `environment variable` with variable name equal to `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and a value of `python`

[image]

3. Checking whether solution works or not?

As you can see after launching `PySpark`, `a.take()` only works when `PySpark` able to detect `Python`

[image]

or you can also confirm by running `wordcount.py` using `command` shown in your mentioned document.

```
C:\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3>bin\spark-submit examples\src\main\python\wordcount.py README.md
```

this is the output of the above command i.e., `counting words in a file`

```
22/06/24 11:53:33 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0

...

guide](https://spark.apache.org/contributing.html): 1
information: 1
get: 1
started: 1
contributing: 1
project.: 1

...
```